# Center a horizontal CSS menu

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS menu using the following CSS.

What is the best way to center the whole menu on the page?

I have tried using another `<div>` outside `<nav>` and setting margins but its just aligning left all the time.

```
nav {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid black;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #000000;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}       

nav ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    color: #000000;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #666666;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/njuVm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center the navigation bar by using the following CSS rules:

```css
nav {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid black;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;                 /* << add this */
    padding: 0;                /* << add this */
    display: inline-block;     /* << add this */
    vertical-align: top;       /* << add this */
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;          /* << add this */
    padding: 0;         /* << add this */
}

nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #000000;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: pink; /* optional... */
}       

nav ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    color: #000000;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #666666;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/DP6Ax/

The key is to set `display: inline-block` for `nav ul`, which will allow your `text-align: center` rule to take effect.

Make sure to zero out margins and paddings  on the `ul` and `li` elements.  Everything else that you did was more or less right, so you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of floating the `li`, you can display them as `inline-block`s.

Then, they will be centered relatively to the `ul` because of `text-align: center`.

Since the `ul` is as wide as the `nav` by default, the `li` will look like centered relatively to the `nav`.

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: block; 
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
nav > ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
nav > ul ul > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
nav > ul ul a:hover {
  color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/add_contact.php">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/view_contact.php">View Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tickets.php">Tickets</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>TEST1</a></li>
        <li><a>TEST2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/invoices.php">Invoices</a></li>
    <li><a href="/itemised_calls.php">Itemised Calls</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, when you float the `ul`'s you have to clear the float by adding `clear` div:

**HTML  :**

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

---

And for centring the menu you should specify a width of the `ul` as in example and randomly I have set the width to `560px` :

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width : 560px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

Take a Look:

http://jsfiddle.net/njuVm/6/